# Calculating week on week growth while accounting for several parameters

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Good everyone!**

I tried my best to find here a previously resolved case but was unable to find anything vaguely similiar.

So, ope someone can help me out:
I have daily entries on new job applications and sources where they found my organisation.

Currently I have the following table: 
[image]

where 
-**Lead_create** is date grouped by week starting from first week of January 2017 and going all the way to today.

-**Source** is the source where the applicants found my organisation

-**Count** is a count of number of applicats that found me through a unique source within each week

**What I need:**
To calculate a percentage change of number of applicants coming from a certain source.
For example, if we look at only one perticular source (let's say, Ydirect), I need the following:

[image]

However, I need it to be calculated for ALL my sources (and not just Ydirect).

**What I tried so far:**
I found the combo of LAG and WINDOW function but it just counts the following row

Many thanks in advance!

Best,
John

Comment: 1) MySQL and postgresql are two different products with different sql implementations. Which one do you use? 2) Pls include what you have tried so far and what went wrong with them. Pls also note that statistical solutions may be better at generating the expected results than a general rdbms.

Comment: Your data sample is not correct, why you have 2 record for google in the same date?

Comment: please always provide data as text instead of pictures!

Comment: @MobasherFasihy Google and google are two different sources

Comment: Have you checked my answer? is it ok or no?

Comment: Do not ask any question, when it is not important for you. You only disturb other peoples, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

this may be your desired one

```
select t.*,
   (100 * t.count / tprev.count) /  100
from applicationCount t left join
   applicationCount tprev
   on tprev.lead_create = t.lead_create - interval 7 day AND 
   tprev.source = t.source
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.source ASC, t.id ASC;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a89c1/31) link

out put is like:
[image]